# Simple way to get required BooleanField in form in django

Tags: python, django

```
class Participant(models.Model):
        first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Imię')
        last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nazwisko')
        email   = models.EmailField(verbose_name='E-mail')
        nr_telefonu = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, verbose_name='Nr telefonu')
        regulamin_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Wyrażam')
        regulamin_2 = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Wyrażam')
        created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What can I do to get a required BooleanField from a user? When I tried to use the `required = True` argument, it still didn't work. Is there anyone who can resolve that problem?

```
    def home(request):
        #return HttpResponse("hi");
            form = ParticipantCreateForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()

            context = {'form': form }  

        return render(request, 'apka/base.html', context)
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Your field always has a value, False or True and you set the default to False. So whatever the user does, it has a value, which will pass validation. What do you want?

Comment: I would like to force the user to check the box in case he doesn't want to. Each form must be completed with the option selected

Comment: I would like BooleanField  to work the same way as CharField when I use blank = False

Comment: But that’s not how a BooleanField works. Required means it need to have a value. You want the value to be true that’s not the same as CharField. Just add a clean method on your ParticipantCreateForm that checks if the value is True and raises a Validtion error if it’s not true. If you call the method `clean_regulamin_1()` it will automatically be called by Django.

Comment: Cen you show me the correct cod with method clean_regulamin_1()?

Comment: Your code in your answer below is correct, just change the name of the method

Comment: but where i have to put that cod? and for what name i have to change?

Comment: On the Form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add a custom validation method for the field in the form that requires it to equal True for validation to pass. But i don't know where i have to use them

```
regulamin_1 =  regulamin_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Wyrażam')

   def clean_patient_agreement(self):
        pa_value = self.cleaned_data.get('regulamin_1',False)

        ## Return value if True (checked)
        if pa_value:
            return pa_value

        ## Raise exception if not checked
        raise ValidationError('Must check patient agreement box to proceed')
```